# When going over a binary file in c, do I go by bits or bytes?

Tags: c, offset, binaryfiles

I have a long binary string which contains a number of bytes,
I need to use `fseek` to get to a specific byte in the string.

I know I need to calculate the offset but I'm not sure if the offset
is calculated by bits or bytes. If I need to get to the 3rd byte for example
I need to advance the indicator by 3 or by (3*8=)24?

Comment: Don't hard code `8`.  Use CHAR_BITS instead.  It's not just because some platforms have bytes of size 16, or 32, or 9, but also because a human reader can't tell if `8` is the number of bits in a byte or the number of nibbles in a word, or the number of notes in an octave, or the number of legs on an octopus.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Thanks for the tip. I am not using explicit `8` as I did not attach any real code in here. That was a methodical question, but thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

The  [fseek()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.  The new position, `measured in bytes`, is obtained by adding `offset` bytes to the position specified by `whence`.

If whence is set to `SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END`, the offset is relative to the `start  of  the  file,  the current  position  indicator,  or  end-of-file`, respectively.

If you are working with text file

```
First Byte position  ==>  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
Second Byte position ==>  fseek(fp,1,SEEK_SET);
Third Byte position  ==>  fseek(fp,2,SEEK_SET);
```

You just need to specify `Number of byte` and `not Number of byte * 8`

Answer (score 1):

[`fseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/fseek.html) takes offset as the number of bytes, not bits:

> The new position, **measured in bytes** from the beginning of the file, shall be obtained by adding offset to the position specified by whence. (emphasis is mine).

Comment: I actually read the exact same documentation file, I just didn't know if it takes for both ascii and binary files.

Comment: @Quaker encoding vs. binary does not make a difference to `fseek`: it offers a very low-level positioning functionality regardless of the mode in which the `FILE*` has been open.